# People Search lastname begins with letter

Tags: 2010, people-search

While using People Search with a specific letter (default.aspx?k=LastName:s), it will show all people where the lastname contains the letter "s".

How can I change this showing all people where the lastname begins with the letter "s"?

Answer (score 1):

use * symbol - k=lastname:s*. As far as I know contains is not allowed in keyword queries.

Comment: please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx - contains is not supported by KWQ in search. But begin is possible